# Laravel: How to create accessors and mutators if table column's name is in dot notation form?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5

I have table which consists on dot notation columns, I want create accessors and mutators?

I have tried it using camel case, small case, snake case with no luck.

here is the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `customer_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `store_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `payment_method` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `payment_method_title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_updated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `currency` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer_note` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `transaction_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `billing.first_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `billing.last_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `billing.company` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `billing.address_1` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `billing.address_2` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `billing.city` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `billing.state` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `billing.postcode` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `billing.country` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `billing.email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `billing.phone` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shipping.first_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shipping.last_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shipping.company` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shipping.address_1` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `shipping.address_2` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `shipping.city` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shipping.state` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shipping.postcode` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shipping.country` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shipping_lines.method_title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shipping_lines.method_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shipping_lines.total` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shipping_lines.total_tax` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `coupon_lines.code` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `taxvat` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer_email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `increment_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `imported` tinyint(1) DEFAULT 0,
  `wp_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `wp_store_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

Comment: First, fire the person who did this

Comment: Yah!..but that's not the answer!

Comment: Next change the column names to not use dot notation

Comment: can't change on the final stage.

Comment: What's your question? Where are your accessors/mutators?

Comment: public function getShippingAddress1Attribute($value){
        if($value){
          $address = explode("\n", $value);
          return $address[0];
        }
    }

Comment: You *can't change on the final stage* and yet you haven't been able to access the data in your code?

Comment: I just want to do this on this way. just asking, is it possible to do in this way?

Comment: Main reason of asking that, this is also a case, Laravel should have way around to achieve this.